# Automate the webstart process

Tags: java, java-web-start, code-signing, jnlp

The requirement is to automate the java webstart process. After clicking the JNLP file, its loading and displaying the below image
[image]

There is no option for trust always here. I am aware of in Java 7 Update 51, java tighten the security. So I have signed jars with public code signing certificate provided by symantec, so there is no need of adding this site in java control pannel exception list or reduce the security level (both are not allowed in the customer environment). Is there any possibility to make this security question to disappear and run the jars automatically?

**SOLUTION**

Added the below two attributes in MANIFEST.MF, and it worked.

```
Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added the below two attributes in MANIFEST.MF file and it worked.

```
Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a signed JNLP file you don't sign the JNLP file itself, but you include the JNLP file inside the directory structure before the JAR file is created and then signed. The JNLP file must be named APPLICATION.JNLP and is included in the JNLP-INF subdirectory. The JAR file is then created and signed in the usual manner. When a web start application is started, the JNLP file used must be identical to the JNLP file in the signed JAR in order for the application to run.

The [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) lesson in the Java Tutorial explains how to sign a JAR file.

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/signing_a_jnlp_file

Comment: Generally link only answers are discouraged. You should pull some of the most relevant answer from the link and quote it in your answer. This website should be able to act as a standalone reference.